# mv command deleted source files even though the file was not fully moved

Tags: linux, mv

I was using mv command to move multiple files from the directory A to directory B.  The file system where the directory B is located was full, so I received corresponding messages. However, files were moved empty (size 0) and source files were deleted. So, I lost practically all the files that I intended to move.
Is it the way it should behave?

Comment: Were you moving within the same filesystem or across different filesystems?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't supposed to happen. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76727/mv-has-failed-because-of-insufficient-disk-space-what-now and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43014/what-does-mv-do-in-case-of-errors/43017#43017

Comment: No, it isn't the way it _should_ behave, but maybe you have found a bug in `mv` in whichever Linux you're using. You should have got no target files on failures, not zero length files. Alternatively, there may be a problem with the drivers for the target file-system.

Comment: It shouldn't behave like this – in a sense: nobody wants it to behave like this. I guess another explanation (beside a bug in `mv`) is buggy/unreliable target filesystem, whatever it was, that threw messages to you but made `mv` believe all went well.

Comment: Were you moving from one partition to another (either on one drive to another, or within a drive)? That's the only case where this could have happened. Could you provide the full `mv` command you used, the full paths of the `src` and `dst` and an output of `sudo mount`?

Answer (score 2):

Were you moving across a mount point? Normally, the way mv works is to simply rename a file.  A file's full name includes its absolute path, which is why renaming and moving are the same command.

However, if the new location is under a different mount point than the older one, renaming cannot work, because the file is physically located within a different partition.

What mv does in this case is silently copies and deletes the file. This operation, however, isn't that reliable, as I've found from personal experience. It doesn't always check to make sure the copying is sucessful before deleting.

Quite frankly, it's completely unnecesarry for mv to even try to behave this way, when what you should be doing is simply using the cp command followed by the rm command whenever transfering information accross mount points.

By causing what should be a simple command to perform behind-the-scenes magic without the user's knowledge, the authors of the command have created a less transparent system, in addition to one more error prone.

Comment: I was not renaming, was just moving files from the main landing directory to the archive directory.

Comment: damn... such a disappointment because now I've lost all my files, but thank you for clarifying because this was what happened to me... never going to use mv across links from now on